# How to get clicked element innerText as a state with React useState hook

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was trying to get innterText/Menu Title with onclick event in React. It's getting the menu title properly but every time it's getting clicked it's just putting the same title again and again. (i.e. Menu Title Menu Title) how can I prevent this? Thanks in advance.

```jsx
const [menuName, setMenuName] = useState()

const handleMenuName = (event) => {
    setMenuName(event.target.innerText)
  }

console.log(menuName) //output Menu Title Menu Title Menu Title...

<div onClick={(event) => handleMenuName(event)}>Menu Title</div>
```

I have tried like this but not working

```jsx
 const handleMenuName = (event) => {
    const menusName = event.target.innerText
    setMenuName((prevState) => {
      console.log(prevState === menusName)
      if (prevState === menusName) return
      return menusName
    })
  }
```

Comment: Check if it changed before setting the value (and log inside the handler otherwise you'll log the text for each refresh, not for each click).
OR
`useEffect(() => { console.log(menuMenu); }, [menuName]);`

Comment: can you please explain a bit better what do you mean by  it's just putting the same title again and again ? you mean it's appending Menu Title to the menuName state ?

Comment: @Mob_Abominator sorry if I couldn't explain well. but yeah it's appending Menu Title.